# NSWorkspace throwing error when bridging library with swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, pocket

I'm using the [pocket api](https://github.com/Pocket/Pocket-ObjC-SDK) and bridging it over to use with swift and it's throwing the error "Semantic issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'NSWorkspace'" for the following line in their obj-c API:

`[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];`

The app is targeting os 10.9+, so it should be available.

Any ideas on what can cause that error?

**Update**
I've also tested in iOS, and it's returning the same error, but with 'UIApplication' instead of 'NSWorkspace'.

I also forgot to mention I had to use the `-fno-objc-arc` flag in the *Build Phases* tab so the lib doesn't freak out over ARC.

Comment: Are you writing an application extension? Some APIs are not available from app extensions.

Comment: No, standard mac app. I haven't even gotten passed the AppDelegate yet trying to get this bug worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working on iOS and OSX by adding the following code after the imports in *PocketAPI.m* and *PocketAPILogin.m*:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif

#ifdef __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
   #import <Appkit/AppKit.h>
#endif
```